# Next.js production build doesn't apply css variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, postcss

I have the next postcss config

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      'postcss-preset-env',
      {
        browsers: 'last 2 versions, IE 11, not dead',
        preserve: false,
        features: {
          'custom-media-queries': true,
          'custom-properties': true,
          'nesting-rules': true
        },
        importFrom: ['src/styles/variables.css']
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And this file with css variables

```
@custom-media --desktop screen and (min-width: 768px);
@custom-media --mobile screen and (max-width: 767px);

:root {
  --montserrat: montserrat, sans-serif;
  --sfProDisplay: sf pro display, sans-serif;
  --helvetica: helvetica, sans-serif;
  --blue: #315efb;
  --middleBlue: #2c54e2;
  --darkBlue: #274bc8;
  --lightBlue: #e0ebff;
  --green: #21a038;
  --grey: #62687f;
  --darkGray: #343b4c;
  --blueGray: #8d96b2;
  --cloudGray: #f3f4f7;
  --cloudGray7: #afb6c9;
  --darkCarbone: #1f2431;
  --paleYellow: #fffde5;
  --red: #ff564e;
}
```

After i built my project via next build && next export, colors are not displayed correctly. For example, color: var(--blueGray), instead color: #8d96b2. Has anybody idea what's wrong?

[image]
[image: Dev server]

Comment: May you share an example of a defined colour property, it's usage, how it should look, and how it currently looks?

Comment: So something with PostCSS is removing the `--` from the custom properties?

Comment: Yeah, i added photo. It looks like on photo, but it should be color: #8d96b2, instead color: var(--blueGray)

Comment: That output is correct. The CSS color _should be_ `--blueGray`. If you hover your mouse over it, it should tell you what the browser says that property currently is. Remember they're not like SASS variables, they're run time, not compile time.

Comment: But if i run dev server, the color is #8d96b2 and displays correctly

Comment: May you share an example of that? The production output is correct. The dev server output might not be

Comment: yeah, i added dev server styles

Comment: I don't have any suggestions why the dev-server outputs that, but it's not correct if you're using custom properties.

Comment: because it makes this plugin https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-properties

Comment: Then my question becomes, has postcss been setup correctly? I'm not sure I can help there though.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly this problem, including the difference between the `next run dev` and the exported output. I made a demo repository here: https://github.com/hallvors/next-export-test including a screenshot of the difference between running in dev mode and rendering built result.

Comment: The display is correct. It should display the variable instead of the color. You should also be able to programmatically change --blueGray to another color, and all css styles using `var(--blueGray)` should change to the color

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I want to use PostCSS and its postcss-custom-properties plugin to replace all `vars(—variable-name-declared-in-root)` so the output stays compatible with older browsers w/o CSS variables. If this actually happens on running `next dev` why does it not happen on build/export?

Comment: Now this problem got even weirder because all of a sudden I can no longer reproduce the issue I saw.. Maybe some caching somewhere was fooling me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should import your CSS variables directly in your styles section and not in config. but I might have got you wrong

Comment: The problem is if i use develop mode, everything work correctly, without directing imports. But in production build don't work

Answer (score 0):

This may not be worth the bounty but from [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config).

> CSS variables are not compiled because it is not possible to safely do
> so. If you must use variables, consider using something like Sass
> variables which are compiled away by Sass.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but should that be interpreted as "Next build process will not use postcss-custom-properties"? I interpret that as if one just creates a Next.js website using CSS variables and build it with no measures, they would be output un-changed.  I'm expecting setting up  a postcss config using postcss-custom-properties to change that, and it appears to work that way when running `next dev` :)

Answer (score -1):

Global CSS needs to be included in the `/pages/_app` file.

From the [Adding a Global Stylesheet](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet)
 documentation:

> To add a (global) stylesheet to your application, import the CSS file within
> `pages/_app.js`.
>
> (...) In development, expressing stylesheets this way allows your
> styles to be hot reloaded as you edit them—-meaning you can keep
> application state.
>
> In production, all CSS files will be automatically concatenated into a
> single minified `.css` file.

Make sure you import the file where the CSS variables are defined in your custom `_app`.

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../styles/variables.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed _app.js to say ``` 
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../styles/vars.css'
```
but it does not change the rendering and the odd difference between running in dev mode and building/exporting.

Comment: @hallvors Note that in your repo the CSS variables are located in the `vars.css` file in the root (not in `styles` folder) - you need to import that in your case.